# Select specific records and change its values

Tags: mysql

I have a table filled with (DUTCH) holidays in the past and future and I need to change the name and date for a specific holiday. Since we don't have a Queen anymore, but a King, Queensday is no longer a holiday. Now its Kingsday. AND it is celebrated on a different date.

This is my current table:

```
68  NL  2014-04-30  Queensday  
77  NL  2015-04-30  Queensday  
88  NL  2016-04-30  Queensday  
97  NL  2017-04-30  Queensday  
106 NL  2018-04-30  Queensday  
115 NL  2019-04-30  Queensday  
124 NL  2020-04-30  Queensday  
134 NL  2021-04-30  Queensday
```

I want to change all records where `description='Queensday'` into `description='Kingsday'` AND `date=date-3days` (since it is celebrated each April 27th) but only where year of the date is greater than 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update table
set 
  description = 'Kingsday',
  <yourdateField> = date_sub(<yourdateField>, interval 3 DAY)
where description = 'Queensday'
and year(<yourdateField>) > 2013
```

bonus (?)

```
update country
 set 
   politicalSystem = 'democracy',
   comment = 'easier to manage holidays'
 where 
   politicalSystem = 'royalty'
```

Comment: I did an answer at the same time. Did my dateadd will works as your date_sub? I'm not MySQL expert.

Comment: @Wagner see comment  in your answer;)